# Doctrine 2.1: Basic annotation mapping

Tags: php, orm, annotations, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have tried a couple of different examples I found on forums and even on the official documentation, but just cant seem to understand and make this work.

It's quite simple, yet anything i write does not work!

So, I have `Category` entity and a `Site` entity. One category should have many sites. Thats it, really. How to map them?

I understand I should have a field *sites* in `Category` entity as a OneToMany relationship, and *category* field in the `Site` entity as ManyToOne?

The most basic code I tried is this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Site", mappedBy="category")
 */
protected $sites;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category")
 */
protected $category;
```

This gives no error when calling (in Symfony 2):

`app/console doctrine:generate:entities TestSampleBundle\Entity\Category (or Site)`, but says:

`Namespace "..." does not contain any mapped entities.`

I am quite new to Doctrine, so please no insults, I agree that I might not be able to understand the examples, and they could be perfectly working, but even so, I need someone to explain this in 2 sentences, so I would know where to start from. I haven't ever managed to make mappings work.

Comment: Would you mind showing your namespace and use part ?

Comment: Yes, here are the complete entities: http://pastebin.com/NvcYKVj9 http://pastebin.com/UT3Zv5Ba I get the error by trying to generate them through Symfony's console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking in your pastebin I recognize you might have some issues with your namespace:

Try replacing

```
namespace Tony\NachalotoBundle\Entity\Catalog;
```

with

```
namespace Tony\NachalotoBundle\Entity;
```

and make sure to place it in the folder

```
src/Tony/NachalotoBundle/Entity
```

As a general advice: Always make sure your namespace matches your folder structure and your usage in symfony commands. The autoloader only works well when you pay attention to namespaces!

Comment: Well, both my entities are in the same folder / namespace and as Doctrine documentation says if they are in the same namespace they can see each other with no problem. I suspect, though, that my generation command might be incorrect..

Comment: Indeed, you use namespace TestSampleBundle\Entity\Category in your command where it should say Tony\NachalotoBundle\Entity\Catalog. Mind that this is not symfony2 convention, which says you should place your entities directly in Tony\NachalotoBundle\Entity.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, my command was incorrect, and I've also missed `inversedBy` in the ManyToOne side. It works now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you don't have any other doctrine declarations format (yml, xml, ...).

In my case, there was a file inside  MyBundle, ../Resources/doctrine/Users.orm.yml that was causing doctrine not reading annotations on Entities definitions.

Removing this folder, as it was no needed cause class User was defined via annotations, solved my problem.